# How are WorkerHarnessThreads managed in Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is the option `numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads` used by cloud-dataflow runner now?

Earlier the `PipelineOptions` property `numberOfWorkerHarnessThreads` was specified in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#configuring-pipelineoptions-for-execution-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service) and was displayed in Dataflow Job Monitoring UI under Pipeline options. Both are missing now.

If this is not used, how are the worker threads managed now?

Answer (score 1):

The option is still there. You can find it in [`DataflowPipelineDebugOptions`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ce77db10cdd5f021f383721a90f30205aff0fabe/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/options/DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java#L178).

Comment: I was asking whether its really used by Dataflow. If yes, why is it missing in UI and PipelineOptions Dataflow documentation.

Comment: AFAICT, it's used in Dataflow worker at https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fd946acdd035fd10914ea6eab18752e61afceb41/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/worker/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/worker/DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java#L95. I don't know why it's not well-documented on Dataflow website. I think it's missing because it is a debug option.

Comment: I guess ''use_multiple_sdk_containers' experiment supersedes this option. Instead of having multiple theads in the runner, you have several containers running your code in parallel (which speeds up a bit Python dataflows)

Comment: I guess the 'use_multiple_sdk_containers' experiment supersedes this option: Dataflow now runs your code in several containers and you can get extra parallelism (specially useful in python worflows).